# How to work with with Google playground code in offline?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

This script it need to call from Net.is that possible to download the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really, I don't see any benefits of having this downloaded. The very reason Google provides these APIs is to benefit from sharing cached resources across the web. For instance it's about letting the user's browser use the same cached copy of jQuery script across different websites. You can also check [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/announcing-ajax-libraries-api-speed-up-your-ajax-apps-with-googles-infrastructure)

Apart from allowing you to access a shared library, other scripts you can load from here are all generally Google APIs which in most cases have something to do with Google resources available on the web.